# JList with own data model

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am trying to figure out how to use a `JList` correctly. I am struggling with the usage of lists in combination with my own classes/data models. 
My goal is to to extract the list in a separate class and change the displayed data within the list from multiple actions (Button Events / Action Listeners).

For example: If the user has chosen a compatible CSV file, the list should show the contents of that file. The file itself contains a simple playlist which is compound as follows: Artist; Title; File path

If the user adds a further song to the playlist, the list should "refresh". I've read something about "FireContents..." but I firstly would like to know how to use those lists properly.

I am going to add the relevant parts of my source code. Any help & advice are appreciated.

```
public class MusicTrack implements project.model.Track{
private String strArtist;
private String strTitle;
private String strFilepath;

public MusicTrack(String strArtist, String strTitle, String strFilepath){
    this.strArtist = strArtist;
    this.strTitle = strTitle;
    this.strFilepath = strFilepath;
}
```

MusicPlayer:

```
public class MusicPlayer implements ActionListener{

private JFrame mainframe;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MusicPlayer window = new MusicPlayer();
                window.mainframe.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public MusicPlayer() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    mainframe = new JFrame();
    mainframe.setTitle("MusicPlayer");
    mainframe.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    // menu & menuitems
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    mainframe.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("Datei");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenuItem mnItemLoadNewList = new JMenuItem("Neue Liste laden");
    mnFile.add(mnItemLoadNewList);


    JMenuItem mnItemLoadLIst = new JMenuItem("Liste laden & anhängen");
    mnFile.add(mnItemLoadLIst);

    JMenuItem mnItemSave = new JMenuItem("Speichern");
    mnFile.add(mnItemSave);

    JMenuItem mnItemNewEntry = new JMenuItem("Neuer Eintrag");
    mnFile.add(mnItemNewEntry);

    JMenu mnSort = new JMenu("Sortieren");
    menuBar.add(mnSort);

    JMenuItem mnItemArtist = new JMenuItem("nach Interpret");
    mnSort.add(mnItemArtist);

    JMenuItem mnItemTitle = new JMenuItem("nach Titel");
    mnSort.add(mnItemTitle);

    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{450, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{227, 29, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    mainframe.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;


    JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
    listPanel.setLayout(gridBagLayout);
    mainframe.getContentPane().add(listPanel);
    listPanel.setVisible(true);



    // Buttons
    JButton btnPlayAll = new JButton("Play All");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnPlayAll = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnPlayAll.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc_btnPlayAll.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_btnPlayAll.gridx = 0;
    gbc_btnPlayAll.gridy = 1;
    mainframe.getContentPane().add(btnPlayAll, gbc_btnPlayAll);

    //Action- & Eventlistener, registering individual ActionListener per Button
    mnItemLoadNewList.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JFileChooser fChoose = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter fExt = new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV", "csv");
            fChoose.setFileFilter(fExt);
            int returnVal = fChoose.showOpenDialog(null);
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                JList<Track> list = new JList<Track>();
                ListModel<Track> listModel = new DefaultListModel<Track>();
                list.setModel(listModel);
                JScrollPane sPane = new JScrollPane(list);
                sPane.add(listPanel);                   
            }
        };          
    });

    // FIXME - Attach!
    mnItemLoadLIst.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JFileChooser fChoose = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter fExt = new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV", "csv");
            fChoose.setFileFilter(fExt);
            int returnVal = fChoose.showOpenDialog(null);
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){                   

            }
        };          
    });

    // FIXME - Save!
    mnItemSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JFileChooser fChoose = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter fExt = new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV", "csv");
            fChoose.setFileFilter(fExt);
            int returnVal = fChoose.showOpenDialog(null);
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                File selcdFile = new File(fChoose.getSelectedFile().toString());
                PlayList myPL = new PlayList();
                myPL.getTracks();
                try {
                    myPL.save(selcdFile);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainframe, e1 + "\n\nBitte eine kompatible Datei wählen.", "MusicPlayer Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
            }               
        };          
    });

    mnItemNewEntry.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            NewEntry myNewEntry = new NewEntry(new JFrame(), "Neuer Eintrag");
            myNewEntry.setSize(300, 240);
            myNewEntry.setLocationRelativeTo(mainframe);
            myNewEntry.setVisible(true);

        };          
    });
```

Class NewEntry

```
            // FIXME - btnChooseFile
        btnChooseFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                JFileChooser fChoose = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter fExt = new FileNameExtensionFilter("MP3", "mp3"); // FIXME add wave etc.
                fChoose.setFileFilter(fExt);
                int returnVal = fChoose.showOpenDialog(null);
                if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    txtFilepath.setText(fChoose.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                }
            };          
        });
```

PlayList (contains simple methods such as saving, loading)

```
public class PlayList implements project.model.PlayList{

private List<Track> playList = new LinkedList<>();
private String strDelimiter = ";";

public void setPlayList(List<Track> playList) {
    this.playList = playList;
}
```

Code for JList, that still gives me headache.

```
        ListModel<PlayList> theModel = new DefaultListModel<PlayList>();
    JList<PlayList> myJList = new JList<PlayList>(theModel);
    for(int i = 0; i < myPlayList.getTracks().size(); i++){
        theModel.addElement(i);
    }
    JScrollPane myScrollPane = new JScrollPane(myJList);
    mainframe.add(myScrollPane);
```

Comment: Well, don't create a new instance of `JList` in your `actionPerformed` method, instead, create one single instance and simply change the `ListModel` when you want to

Comment: *"I am going to add the relevant parts of my source code."* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). `mainframe.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);` Stop guessing.  Just `pack()` the frame (after the components are added)!  BTW - that data (three datum per row) is  best suited to a `JTable`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Do I unterstand that correctly, that I should create a new class "myJList" to create one, single instance and change the ListModel by Getter & Setter methods from the different actionPerformed methods?

Comment: No, in you're exists code (actionPerformed), you are creating a new instance of JList each time it's called, you don't need to do that. You just create an instances field, add it to the UI when you create it and simply change the ListModel as you need

Comment: Thanks for that information & help. Going to do it as you told it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really start by reading the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for `JList`, as there's quite a lot to cover. Here's the overview, though:

1. Create a list model - most of the time [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) will do.
2. Create a JList, and pass the model in the constructor (so that it uses that model).
3. Initialize the list, e.g. set the selection mode, and possibly a custom [`ListCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html).
4. From now on, interact with the model, not the list. The model will fire the events for you.